# Can I get the raw value of arbitrary tokens?

Tags: 7, tokens

This site I'm working on is using tokens in such a way that the escaped (`check_plain()`'d) values provided by the tokens as is is problematic (they're getting double-escaped). Is there some way to specify that I want the raw values for those tokens? I tried just appending ":raw" to the token name, but that didn't seem to work.

I could just write my own tokens for this purpose which only provide the raw values, but I want to see if that's really necessary first.

Answer (score 1):

Garrett,

From your question I can see that you have appended ":raw" to the list of tokens that you are using.

I think that will be "-raw" instead of ":raw". As example, [user:name-raw] instead of [user:name:raw].